# Windows Crashes on nvlddmkm

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, nvidia-geforce

I recently in installed Windows on my computer after having Linux for over 1 year.

Now whenever I start any game I get a bluescreen from nvlddmkm. I understand this is form nVidia, which makes sence since I am playing a game.

I tried:

- Reinstalling the driver which didn't work.
- Installed Windows 8 instead of Windows 7.
- Reinstalled 7.
- Reinstalled my nVidia driver without PhysX.

I am running out of ideas to fix this bluescreen.

Blue screen error:

```
 BCCode:    1000007e
 BCP1:  FFFFFFFFC0000005
 BCP2:  FFFFF8800F90DFFE
 BCP3:  FFFFF880035A1748
 BCP4:  FFFFF880035A0FA0
 OS Version:    6_1_7601
 Service Pack:  1_0
 Product:   256_1
```

I'm using an nVidia 610M (so its an laptop) and 64-bit Windows.

EDIT:

I just installed a asus driver form the asus webpage and now i dont get the blue screen but since this driver is from dec 2011 things work very slow.

Conclusion it cant be broken hardware

Comment: Check out solution here,
http://superuser.com/questions/821244/video-driver-i-think-causes-computer-to-freeze-up-then-continue/1090246#1090246

Answer (score 3):

[0x1000007e](http://errlookup.azurewebsites.net/?err=0x1000007e) = "SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED".

If updating/replacing the drivers/OS didn't help, then to me it seems you most likely have a busted graphics adapter and/or video RAM.

Ensure graphics adapter's cooling apparatus is clean form dust, and working as it should.

If the graphics adapter is integrated into the motherboard and uses system RAM, run [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) for a couple days and test your RAM fully.

If the Memtest86+ comes up clean, or you're using a discrete graphics adapter, then try a known-good replacement adapter. If you don't have spare hardware to try, and/or don't want to buy one to test with, then take it to a repair shop.

Comment: I just installed an old driver from the asus webpage and now i dont get the error but still it work very slow with this old driver so while its technically solved i would like a more recent driver, any idea's why this is?

Comment: Perhaps the newer driver introduces a feature that causes your faulty graphic adapter to fail, and it didn't fail previously because there was no attempt to use the broken bits. ;)  Having said that, sometimes certain driver revisions are buggy with certain chipsets.  If you're not stuck using Asus's drivers (which with mobile chipsets you often are) try getting the latest production version, and latest beta version, of the drivers from nVidia directly and see if they work any better/differently.

Comment: all driver newer than 320.xx cause several BSODs for older cards.